# How to check which button was clicked when all have the same value

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I try to create list of buttons according to code below:

```
for(int ii=0;ii<SomeList.size();ii=ii+4)
{
 %>
  <input type="button" 
   onClick="javascript:void window.open(
     'open some page','1440961293929',
     'width=100,height=100,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,
     scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0'
    );return false;" 
   value="Save" >
<%
}
```

and check which was clicked. Normally I can use `request.getparameter("name")` and get value of button. How to get name value of button (or get some id which button was clicked) if in my case every button has the same value (Save)?

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to your problem.

1. The most straightforward approach is to assign unique IDs to each of your buttons.
2. Another approach is to use `jQuery` event handler as follows:

   ```
   <input type="button" 
     onClick="javascript:void window.open(
     'open some page','1440961293929',
     'width=100,height=100,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,
     scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0'
    );return false;" 
    value="Save" class="myButton" >

   $('.myButton').on('click', function(){
       $(this).addClass("myButtonClicked");
       // Do the desired operations the clicked button
          ....
       // desired operations end
       $(this).removeClass("myButtonClicked");
   });
   ```

Here we add a class to all the buttons of the group and add an event listener to the class. When any button of this class is clicked, the `click` event listener will be fired. Then we can access the clicked button with the `this` variable reference inside the function.

At any point of time, `$('.myButtonClicked')` will refer to the last clicked button.

Working JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/o9qpghz6/).

Comment: But still if I add id to each button for example value of `ii` : `<input type="button" id="<%=ii%>"
   onClick="javascript:void window.open(
     'open some page','1440961293929',
     'width=100,height=100,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,
     scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0'
    );return false;" 
   value="Save" > ` how to get id of clicked button

Comment: @adamadamski: `$('.myButtonClicked')` wil refer to the button. `$('.myButtonClicked').attr('id')` will return the id of the clicked button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use button element instead of input element :

```
for(int ii=0;ii<SomeList.size();ii=ii+4)
{
 %>
 <button name="name" onclick="javascript:void window.open('open some page','1440961293929','width=100,height=100,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0');return true;" value="button<%=ii%>">Save</button>
<%
}
```

This way every button value will be different and all the buttons captions will still be "Save"

Answer (score 0):

```
give all buttons a name and id while creating them process them like:

for(var ii=0;ii<5;ii+=1)
{
  document.write('<input type="button"    onClick="javascript:alert(this.name);void(0);" value="Save" id="'+ii+'" name ="button'+ii+'"/>');

}


or 
-your code-

for(int ii=0;ii<SomeList.size();ii=ii+4)
{
 %>
  <input type="button" 
   onClick="javascript:void window.open(
     'open some page','1440961293929',
     'width=100,height=100,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,
     scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0'
    );return false;" 
   value="Save" name="button<%=ii%>" id="button<%=ii%>">
<%
}
```